# Export/Put and Import/Get

Tags: export, import, function-comparison

I have questions about importing and exporting that don't seem to have up-to-date answers anywhere.

1. What's the difference between Export and Put? Which should I use if I care about how long it takes to execute? Which if I care about file size?
2. What's the difference between `Import` and `Get`? Same follow ups.
3. Why do `Export`/`Put` write to `Directory[]` but `Import`/`Get` read from `$Path`? (If you doubt this, try it yourself. If this isn't true for you, message me to discuss please.)
4. Does it matter what file type I Export/Put to? I've heard of .m and .mx, are either of those optimal? (My use case is a giant 2D table of numerical values, but you could also answer more generally.)

Edit: I've found nothing that even touches on (1) or (3) (except an answer to (1) from 2002 that is likely out of date). Somewhere said `Import` is the same as `Get` for .mx files, but I don't know if it's the same in general, which is why I asked (2). I just added (4) because the explanations I've found of file types don't seem to answer my question of whether one is more time/space-efficient than the other. I'm exporting then importing a giant table, so doing so efficiently is important for me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80535/discussion-on-question-by-max-export-put-and-import-get).

Comment: @Kuba Unfortunately, this chat did not discuss the detailed difference among `Export`, `Put`, and `Save` (and other similar commands described in [Files](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Files.html)).